# Get entries that are enabled and disabled for the site

Tags: craft3, craft-pro

A Craft (3.4 Pro) website has setup two sites, one for each language. There are entries in a section that are enabled and others that are disabled for each language.

I want to get a list of **all** the entries, regardless of whether they are enabled or not.

I know there is a `enabledForSite` parameter but this can be set to either `true` or `false` but not both.

For example the query below returns only enabled entries.

```
{% set items = craft.entries({
  section: 'works',
  enabledForSite: true,
  status: [
    'live', 'pending', 'disabled', 'expired'
  ]
}).all() %}
```

How can I get a list that contains both `enabled` **and** `disabled` entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of Oli from Craft, it turns out the solution is simpler than I thought:

```
{% set items = craft
    .entries()
    .section('works')
    .anyStatus()
    .all() 
%}
```

This returns all entries, enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the code, I think you can pass `enabledForSite: [true, false]` to get both the enabled and disabled entries. So in your case:

```
{% set items = craft.entries({
  section: 'works',
  enabledForSite: [true, false],
  status: [
    'live', 'pending', 'disabled', 'expired'
  ]
}).all() %}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! However I tried this and it doesn't work. I still get the same results (enabled entries)